# How to connect cloud function to cloudsql

Tags: google-cloud-sql

How I can connect cloud function to cloudsql.

```
import psycopg2
def hello_gcs(event, context):

    print("Imported")
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='db_bio' user='postgres' host='XXXX' password='aox199'")
    print("Connected")   
    file = event
    print(f"Processing file: {file['name']}.")
```

Could not connect to cloud sql's postgres version, please help.

Answer (score 5):

Google Cloud Function provides a unix socket to automatically authenticate connections to your Cloud SQL instance if it is in the same project. This socket is located at `/cloudsql/[instance_connection_name]`.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host='/cloudsql/[instance_connection_name]', dbname='my-db', user='my-user',  password='my-password')
```

You can find the full documentation page (including instructions for authentication from a different project) [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Python example mentioned on [this public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36388165#comment185), or use the Node.JS code shown in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql#connecting_to_cloud_sql) to connect to Cloud SQL using Cloud Functions.